# Querying nested maps in Java

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a third-party method (namely [InfoEndpoint.html#invoke()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/InfoEndpoint.html#invoke)) which gives me an object structure using Maps (a Map in a Map in a ...). I would like to navigate in this data structure in a not very ugly way. :)

Here is an example of getting values from a structure like this in a "manual Java way" (line #17-31) and the "Groovy way" (last line): [example](https://github.com/jonatan-ivanov/groovy-training/blob/master/examples/046_SafeDereference02.groovy).

I would like to have something similar to the Groovy way but I don't have Groovy here, the project is pure Java. If it is possible, I don't really want to write code (or too much ugly code) for this; do you happen to know if there is a library which can help me out?

Here is an ugly, Java solution, which I don't want to use:

```
public class MapNavigator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> people = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Object> holmes = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Object> address = new HashMap<>();

        address.put("street", "Baker St");
        holmes.put("address", address);
        people.put("holmes", holmes);

        System.out.println(get(people, "holmes.address.street"));
    }

    public static Object get(Map<String, Object> map, String path) {
        return get(map, Arrays.asList(path.split("\\.")));
    }

    private static Object get(Map<String, Object> map, List<String> pathElements) {
        if (map == null || pathElements.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        else if (pathElements.size() == 1) {
            return map.get(pathElements.get(0));
        }
        else {
            String head = pathElements.get(0);
            List<String> tail = pathElements.subList(1, pathElements.size());

            Object object = map.get(head);
            if (object instanceof Map) {
                return get((Map<String, Object>) object, tail);
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try Apache Commons JXPath: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath/

It pretty much implements XPath for Java objects and has a swag of features.  For your example you could use simple query like this:

```
JXPathContext.newContext(map).getValue("holmes/address/street");
```